# Node - Async waterfall with in a for loop

Tags: node.js, azure, gremlin, async.js

I'm having issues understanding `async.waterfall` when using a for loop:

So I'm using the following waterfall:

```
async.waterfall([
    addVertices,
    countVertices
], finish);
```

with the 3 methods below.

However the issue I am facing is the result in `countVertices` is not accurate i.e. sometimes should 2 and sometimes 1, when it should always show 2.

This leads me to believe the callback from `addVertices` is not actually being called once the for loop is complete.

Could anyone help - is that wrong in calling the callback when the for loop reaches the last iteration?

```
function addVertices(callback) {
    for (var x = 0; x < pData.length; x++) {

        client.execute("g.addV(‘test’).property(‘id’, \"" + pData.id + "\")", { }, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return callback(console.error(err));
            }
        });

        if (x == pData.length-1 ){
            callback(null)
        }

    }

}


function countVertices(callback)
{
    console.log('Running Count');
    client.execute("g.V().count()", { }, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
        return callback(console.error(err));
    }

    console.log("Result: %s\n", JSON.stringify(results));
    callback(null)
});
}


function finish(err, result)
{
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log("Finished");
    console.log('Press any key to exit');

    process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
    process.stdin.resume();
    process.stdin.on('data', process.exit.bind(process, 0));
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop in `addVertices()` will never work properly that way.  `client.execute()` is non-blocking and asynchronous.  So, you'll just run `pData.length` calls to `client.execute()` and then return and they will all finish a long time later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in addVertices.  You can solve it by replacing the for statement with an async.forEach

```
function addVertices(outercallback) {
    async.forEach(pData, function (data, innercallback) {
      client.execute("g.addV('test').property('id', \"" + data.id + "\")", { }, innercallback);
    }, outercallback);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that!